# What is the best way to select an element if the element's index is over 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, selector, equals

Pseudo Code

```
$("#cool ul li.active:eq( > 3)") { // selector if the active li is over 3
     $('#cool ul').animate({right: '+=984'},0);
};
```

What is the best way to select if the li is over 3?

Comment: Can you improve on the question title please.

Comment: Im sorry for the question title - I changed it for a more common use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[:gt selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
if ($("#cool li:gt(3)").hasClass('active')) { 
     $('#cool ul').animate({right: '+=984'},0);
};
```

**EDIT:** Had it correct the first time, thought I had it wrong and made it incorrect, should be back to correct again :P

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#cool ul li:gt(2)").filter('.active').length === 1) {
  $('#cool ul').animate({right: '+=984'},0);
};
```

**EDIT:** Updated code to assume 1 `.active` `li`
**EDIT 2:** Momentarily forgot `:gt()` uses a 0 based index